# Fourier series expansion of $\delta(x-1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series, dirac-delta

I am trying to express
$\delta(x-1)$
on the trigonometric basis

on $L^2([0,1], \mathbb{R})$, given by

$$1, \sqrt{2}\cos(2 \pi j x), \sqrt(2)\sin(2 \pi j x). $$

For example,

$$
\delta(x - 1/2) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n \sqrt{2}\cos(2 \pi j x)
$$
with $c_n = \sqrt{2}\cos(\pi n )$.

When I try to expand $\delta(x -1)$, I get
$$
\delta(x - 1) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} d_n \sqrt{2}\cos(2 \pi j x)
$$
with $d_n = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos(2 \pi n ) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

The result is an even function,

[image]

meaning the reconstruction fails to reproduce
$\delta(x-1)$.

I know delta functions are not elements of
$L^2([0,1], \mathbb{R})$
anyway, but why does
$\delta(x -1/2)$
work and
$\delta(x - 1)$
does not ?

Comment: Use `\cos` to render $\cos$, and for that matter almost every standard function renders better with a backslash before it: `\func`

Comment: Why does that mean the reconstruction has failed? The cosine expansion you have provided will always produce an even function since the cosine is even. Furthermore, in your space, $\delta(x-1)$ is the same as $\delta(x)$ since you're on the $[0,1]$ periodic domain

Comment: @spaceman But I want a function $\delta(x-1)$ that is zero for $x \neq 1$ in $[0,1]$ . Is this impossible due to periodicity ? I thought the periodicity will tell you what happens outside $[0,1]$.

Comment: @kot Note that a numerical simulations cannot fully realise infinite sums. They will truncate at some point and give you an approximation, or I assume you chose the sum to stop evaluating after a certain number of summations. What you have obtained in your plot seems correct. The simulated function is zero everywhere apart from close to x=0 and x=1. If you want the function to be zero closer to 0 and 1, you need to evaluate more terms of the sum

Comment: Furthermore, if you're wondering why there is a peak at 0 also, then this is because you're working in a periodic domain of length 1, and so being at 1 is similar to being at 0. If you want the peak only at 1, then you need to use a different function from $\delta(x-1)$ since then what you're actually asking is that you want the function to be non-zero for $\lim_{x\to 1^-} x$.

Comment: @spaceman Thanks for the comments, yeah, I want a peak only at 1, but it is clearer now that it can not be done using the delta function.

Comment: @spaceman Can you provide as an example a function that has one peak only at 1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formulas are incorrect. The correct formulas are as follows:

---

$\delta(x-\frac{1}{2})=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(1+2\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\cos(\pi n)\ \cos(2 \pi n x)\right),\quad -\frac{1}{2}<x<\frac{3}{2}\tag{1}$

$\delta (x-1)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(1+2\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\cos(2 \pi n x)\right),\quad 0<x<2\tag{2}$

---

Figures (1) and (2) below illustrate both functions are periodic with a period of $1$ which is why formula (2) above evaluates non-zero at $x=0$.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (1)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula (1) for $\delta(x-\frac{1}{2})$ evaluated at $N=100$

---

[image: Illustration of formula (2)]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of formula (2) for $\delta(x-1)$ evaluated at $N=100$

---

If you want the formula for $\delta(x-1)$ to evaluate closer to $0$ at $x=0$ then you need to increase the period as illustrated in formula (3) below. Note formula (3) below is equivalent to dividing formula (1) above by $2$ and evaluating it at $\frac{x}{2}$.

---

$\delta(x-1)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\cos(\pi n)\ \cos (\pi n x)\right),\quad -1<x<3\tag{3}$

---

Figure (3) below illustrates formula (3) above for $\delta(x-1)$ is periodic with period $2$ and evaluates closer to $0$ at $x=0$. Formula (3) only converges in a distributional sense and at $x=0$ actually evaluates to $\pm\frac{1}{2}$ depending on the evaluation limit $N$, more specifically formula (3) evaluates to $\frac{1}{2}(-1)^N$ at $x=0$.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (3)]

**Figure (3)**: Illustration of formula (3) for $\delta(x-1)$ evaluated at $N=100$